# Как заблокировать номер телефона?

Tags: java, android

Хочу сделать так, чтобы при нажатии кнопки - блокировался определенный номер телефона. Хотя бы, чтобы смс не поступали. Номер телефона получаю так:

```
Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(Uri.parse("content://sms"), null, null, null, null);
c.moveToFirst();
String phone_number = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("address"));
```

Возможно ли как-то это сделать?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: такое [например](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22069017/how-to-block-all-incoming-calls-and-text-messages-in-android-programmatically)

Comment: @Andrew, так там же блокируются все исходящие номера? А мне нужен только один.

Comment: так дальше просто проверяйте на ваш номер, если == то блокируем либо пропускаем

Comment: @Andrew, я слышал про липкий список от Google. Его проще поставить, только нужно сделать приложение - приложением по умолчанию, не подскажите, как это сделать?